# Problems with IIS URLRewrite and RewriteCacheEnabled

Tags: caching, azure, url-rewriting, iis-8

I am running a Web-application on Azure Websites for about six month without any trouble. But somehow the environment has changed and i have trouble with my URLRewrite Redirect rule. I guess its caused by an activation of RewriteCacheEnabled.

Here is the rule

```
<rule name="Redirect root to language selection page" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^$" />
  <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\..+" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/detect-region-and-language" />
</rule>
```

Rule: If url is empty (root) check if HTTP_HOST starts with www. and redirect to language detection.
Purpose: Redirect www.domain.com to language-selection but don't do it for language.domain.com.

I debugged the Rewrite Module and got the following output:
[image]

What happens: HTTP_HOST northamerica.domain.com gets redirected to the cached, non-matching entry with a entirely different HTTP_HOST (www.domain.com) without checking the conditions.

Over time the cached entry gets refreshed and is based on the current requested sub-domain. This causes a strange behavior, with a new redirect destination for every sub-domain in a cycle of 5 minutes.

My guess: the rewrite cache entry is keyed by the match URL, which is an empty string. I can't disable RewriteCacheEnabled, because i don't have the permission to change registry entries on azure websites.

I contacted the Microsoft support, but my request is still on hold.

Any help is suggested!

Comment: This Problem is related to a major WAWS Bug, documented here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/ee3a5f97-8a58-4b42-a2d9-a73cd5d12c01/issues-with-redirect-rules-used-in-url-rewrite-feature?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: Bug fixed by Microsoft